# Getting json dynamic key name as string?

Tags: json, go

For example:

```
{"id":
    {"12345678901234":
       {"Account":"asdf",
       "Password":"qwerty"
       "LastSeen":"1397621470",
       }
    }
}
```

A program I've been trying to make needs to get the id as a string and then later use it to check the time in LastSeen.
I've tried using [simplejson](https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson/) and [jsonq](https://github.com/jmoiron/jsonq),but still cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452722/how-to-get-the-key-value-from-a-json-string-in-golang I created a playground out of the right answer: http://play.golang.org/p/L9lUI3LP1I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`RawMessage`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) and make it much simpiler ([`play with it`](http://play.golang.org/p/s3D9U7UUMo)) :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var data []byte = []byte(`{"id": {"12345678901234": {"Account":"asdf", "Password":"qwerty", "LastSeen":"1397621470"}}}`)

type Message struct {
    Id   string
    Info struct {
        Account  string
        Password string
        LastSeen string
    }
}

func main() {
    var (
        tmpmsg struct {
            Data map[string]json.RawMessage `json:"id"`
        }
        msg Message
    )
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmpmsg); err != nil {
        panic(err) //you probably wanna use or something instead
    }

    for id, raw := range tmpmsg.Data {
        msg.Id = id
        if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &msg.Info); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", msg)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Golang blog post on JSON [here](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) it can be done using the encoding/json package. I created a small program to do this as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var data []byte = []byte(`{"id": {"12345678901234": {"Account":"asdf", "Password":"qwerty", "LastSeen":"1397621470"}}}`)

type Message struct {
    id string
    LastSeen int64
} 

var m Message

func main() {
    var i interface {}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &i)
    if err != nil {
        println("Error decoding data")
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
        return
    }
    m := i.(map[string]interface{})

    for k, v := range m {
        println(k)
        im := v.(map[string]interface{})
        for ik, iv := range im {
            println("\t", ik)
            jm := iv.(map[string]interface{})
            for jk, jv := range jm {
                println("\t\t", jk, ": ", jv.(string))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I apologise if this is poor in terms of Go best practices and such, I am new to the language. And I know that some elements of this aren't entirely necessary like the Message type definition but this works, at least on your data.